# Is cross tenant blob access possible in azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am having a hard time understanding Azure docs and terminologies. The problem is this. My customer has an azure bucket and we need to read/write to this bucket. They won't be sharing their storage account credentials either.

This can be achieved in AWS by following this:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/
I have just created an IAM user and asked my customers to allow the necessary permissions in the bucket policy. Thus, with one IAM user and one set of credentials, I can write to multiple buckets belonging to multiple AWS accounts.

Is something like above also possible in Azure?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

they can create a Shared access signature while they can control what kind of access you need to have and also when to expire. 
[image]

Comment: But, they don't have an endpoint from which I can get an SAS. And these blobs are to be  read programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean by "they don't have an endpoint"? The SAS will give you a new connection string that you can use in your app.

Comment: Ok. I can generate the SAS token programmatically because I don't have their credentials. And the customers have no endpoint which returns SAS tokens. I understand what you are suggesting. Generate an SAS token that is valid for ever and for all operations, store this SAS in the DB and use this for every operation. But, that approach is not ok and totally not secure. As anyone with the tokencan u any operation.

Comment: @piequals - You can optionally use a Shared Access *Policy* to generate the SAS, which lets you control, and optionally revoke, access (especially if someone inadvertently gets ahold of the SAS link). You can also use a User Delegation SAS, based on AD, which is even more secure.

Comment: @piequals - also, note that SAS *are* secure, and typically have a short-term lifespan (even though you can set them to last indefinitely) (and no need to store a SAS for future use). Imagine generating a new writable SAS any time someone needs to write content, valid for, say, 20 minutes. Likewise, to read content, just generate a new, short-lived (say, 10 minute), read-only SAS link to the content in question. Once the link expires, it doesn't matter who has it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Exactly. SAS tokens generated with my credentials wont be valid as I don't have read and write permissions. Is there a way the client/customer give  my account  permission to read/write to the bucket?Do they need to add me as a guest user to their AD?And then I can use the same storage account credentials to read and write to their bucket?